# Whenever I use UIWebView loadHTMLString ,it's scrollView.contentOffset.y turns to 0

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

How can I let webView  memorize   `webView.scrowView.contenOffSet`  localtion .So that when download new data has a animation frow down to up  .

`[webView.scrollView  setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

try out this line with JavaScript

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scroll(0,0)"];
```